# Android: ScrollView in RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with ScrollView. I'm trying to get it in RelativeLayout. I have tried some solutions, but nothing works.
Inside RelativeLayout are just TextView-s and EditText-s.
Any help with that, please? Thank you.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id= "@+id/okvirZ">

                <TextView android:text="@string/nastavi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/navodilo" />

                 <TextView android:text="@string/vsakodnevni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/navodilo"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                 <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/navodilo"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/navodilo"
                    android:hint="npr. Nakupi" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navodilo"
                    android:hint="eur"
                    android:gravity="right" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+ dodaj"
                    android:id="@+id/dodajanje1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:onClick="DodajNovoVrstico"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MESEČNI STROŠKI"
                    android:id="@+id/mesecni"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dodajanje1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/mesecni1a"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mesecni"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
                    android:hint="npr. Prevoz" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mesecni1a"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
                    android:hint="eur"
                    android:gravity="right"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+ dodaj"
                    android:id="@+id/dodajanje2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:onClick="DodajNovoVrstico2"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="VARČEVANJE"
                    android:id="@+id/varcevanje"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dodajanje2"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/varcevanje1a"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/varcevanje"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:hint="npr. Avto"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/varcevanje1b"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/varcevanje1a"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mesecni1b"
                    android:hint="eur"
                    android:gravity="right"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+ dodaj"
                    android:id="@+id/dodajanje3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/varcevanje1b"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:onClick = "DodajNovoVrstico3"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SHRANI"
                    android:id="@+id/shrani"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="Shrani"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific?What exactly is the problem that you are facing with ScrollView.Your xml looks fine though.

Comment: There is no scroller then in application...can't scroll up and down..nothing.

Comment: Well wondering is this layout by itself is that its full view?  Because I could see this not be large enough to require scrolling, so no scrolling.

Comment: later it becomes sufficiently large, with click on a button to create new fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id= "@+id/okvirZ">

        <TextView android:text="nastavi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/navodilo" />

        <TextView android:text="nastavi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navodilo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/navodilo"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/navodilo"
            android:hint="npr. Nakupi" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navodilo"
            android:hint="eur"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ dodaj"
            android:id="@+id/dodajanje1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="DodajNovoVrstico"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MESEČNI STROŠKI"
            android:id="@+id/mesecni"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dodajanje1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mesecni1a"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mesecni"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/vsakodnevni1a"
            android:hint="npr. Prevoz" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mesecni1a"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vsakodnevni1b"
            android:hint="eur"
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ dodaj"
            android:id="@+id/dodajanje2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="DodajNovoVrstico2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="VARČEVANJE"
            android:id="@+id/varcevanje"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dodajanje2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/varcevanje1a"
            android:layout_below="@+id/varcevanje"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:hint="npr. Avto"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/varcevanje1b"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/varcevanje1a"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mesecni1b"
            android:hint="eur"
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ dodaj"
            android:id="@+id/dodajanje3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/varcevanje1b"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick = "DodajNovoVrstico3"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SHRANI"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dodajanje3"
            android:id="@+id/shrani"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="Shrani"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately..cause there are two buttons in the same line, then.. with no fillViewport. and this is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:fillViewport="true" or set it to false.
Check the android developer docs for more info.As it defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

Here's the link to the developer guide
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView must have  only one child 'LinearLayout'.So you should put you 'RelativeLayout' in a 'LinearLayout'.Like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/okvirZ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```